# Kivy slider override on_touch_up

Tags: python, slider, kivy

I am trying to build my first kivy app and create a simple audio cutting tool. I am using the slider widget to show the position in a playing song (that works so far) but I would like to enable the user to move the slider to a desired position and play the song from that chosen position.

Code I have so far:

file main.py:

automatic moving when the song is playing (callback of clock interval):

```
def my_callback(self, dt):
    if not self.loaded:
        pass
    else:
        if self.playing:
            self.position = self.song.get_pos()
            self.truePos_slider.value = 100 * self.position / self.duration
```

when user touches the slider and move it to another position this should happen:

```
def slider_move(self):
    if self.loaded:
        self.position = (self.truePos_slider.value/100) * self.duration
```

file layout.kv:

```
...
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Slider:
                id: truePos_slider
                on_release: root.slider_move()
...
```

The problem is that the Slider from kivy doesn't have the on_release event as Button has. I think my problem is similar as described here:

[Kivy slider event on_release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127576/kivy-slider-event-on-release/44620490#44620490)

I actually like the solution from inclement, but I don't know where exactly should I put the code of MySliderSubclass with the override method in order to make my layout.kv file recognize it. Could you please help me?

I am sorry if it's a stupid question, I am actually new to Python too...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight thank you for your help! I added the important parts of my code as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `on_touch_up`, just replace `on_release` in your .kv file with it, all events can be called like that. You don't actually need to inherit the slider class.
`on_touch_up` is an event that is shared by all widgets because it is implemented in the widget class itself.

Comment: thank you for your advise @KGS but unfortunatelly, the `on_touch_up` is not working the way I need it to work. If I write `on_touch_up` on the place of `on_release` the function `root.slider_move()` is called on each touch up in the whole app, even from other buttons and widgets, not only on touch up of the specific slider...

Comment: this happens because in kivy events are passed to all widgets in order, unless you interrupt the event bubbling by returning `True` in the appropriate function, and/or by triggering the event only if the touch collides with the widget. Refer to this: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change **on_release** to **on_touch_up** in your **kv** file. You also have to pass two params: **touch** object (it's within args[1]) and **self** object (your slider). Then within your **slider_move** function, having touch and slider object you can check if **on_touch_up** event is fired because your slider was grabbed or not. This will avoid to process other's **on_touch_up** event source.

Here is proper use of **on_touch_up** event in your case:

```
def slider_move(self, touch, widget):
    if touch.grab_current == widget:
        if self.loaded:
            self.position = (self.truePos_slider.value/100) * self.duration
```

file layout.kv:

```
        BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Slider:
            id: truePos_slider
            on_touch_up: root.slider_move(args[1], self)
```