# Kivy slider event on_release in .kv

Tags: button, kivy, slider

I'm pretty new to Kivy and I'm trying to use the Slider widget. I don't want a function to be executed on_value but rather as soon as the slider is released. How can I implement something like on_release (which exists for Buttons) in the Slider class?

Ou seja, em vez de

```
Slider:
on_value: root.do_something()
```

eu quero ter

```
Slider:
on_release: root.do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

The event `on_release` is provided by the *mixin* class `ButtonBehavior`. The class `Slider` is not inherited from `ButtonBehavior`, that's why you can't expect that event in `Slider`. You may also have problem if you want to define a class inheriting from `ButtonBehavior` and `Slider` due to the `on_touch_up` event.

Check more on Kivy documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **on_touch_up** event. You have to pass **touch** object passed to on_touch_up (args[1]) and **slider** object (self), then check if event was fired because your slider was grabbed to avoid of firing on_slider_release method from other sources.

Here is and example:

Within your kv file:

```
Slider:
    on_touch_up: root.on_slider_release(args[1], self)
```

Then on_slider_release implementation:

```
def on_slider_release(self, touch, widget):
    if touch.grab_current == widget:
        print('my_slider has been released')
```